# JavaScript - remove indexes from following array using array prototype methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of users as follows. I am trying to filter out the admins by finding the indices of the admins in the users array and filtering those indices out.

```
var users = [
  {name: "Jeff", IsAdmin: false},
  {name: "Jonah", IsAdmin: true},
  {name: "Jonathan", IsAdmin: true}
];

var admins = users.findIndex(function (user) {
     user.IsAdmin == true;
});

var regularUsers = users.filter(function (value, index) {
    return admins.indexOf(index) == -1;
});
```

The routine above does not work as admins returns null and the filter function does not work properly.

Is there an easier way to write this?

Comment: Can you clarify? If all you want to do is remove admins from the users array, then `var nonAdmins = users.filter(user => !user.IsAdmin)` should suffice (same without the negation to create an admins only array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to filter by the attribute IsAdmin.

Further, you don't need to compare boolean to either `true` or `false`, just use it within your condition, i.e:

```
//You don't need that because `IsAdmin` is a boolean attribute.
return user.IsAdmin == true

//So, use that attribute directly.
return user.IsAdmin
```

```js
var users = [
  {name: "Jeff", IsAdmin: false},
  {name: "Jonah", IsAdmin: true},
  {name: "Jonathan", IsAdmin: true}
];

var admins = users.findIndex(function (user) {
     return !user.IsAdmin;
});
console.log(admins);

var regularUsers = users.filter(function (user) {
    return !user.IsAdmin;
});

console.log(regularUsers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var regularUsers = users.filter(function (user) {
    return !user.IsAdmin;
});
```

Filter adds the user to the list if you return true

Answer (score 1):

`findIndex` returns a single index, not an array of indices. And filtering by index is really inefficient anyway - just go for the predicate directly:

```
const admins = users.filter(user => user.IsAdmin);
const regularUsers = users.filter(user => !user.IsAdmin);
```